# Tableview section ordered last

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How would I use a NSFetchedResultsController such that one particular section is listed last?  I am currently grouping items by department, and ordering by name:

```
 // sort
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"department" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateAdded" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // fetch results, sectioned by department
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:list.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"department" cacheName:nil];
```

I would like a specific department to always be returned last, however. Can I do this with a combination of sort descriptors, or should I be trying to work it out in the cellForIndexPath methods?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a flag in the database on the one that needs to be last (last==1, default 0), and using this flag as the primary sort descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
- (id)initWithKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending comparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

and you define a comparator method which will return a NSComparisonResult according to the alphabetical order for any of your department except than the specific one. for this one, you will always return NSOrderedDescending.

that should do the trick.